# Print text metadata under a plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Suppose I have a set of data points which I want to plot with `matplotlib` and `Python 3`. However, these points are better understood if some additional information (or metadata) are added. This metadata is simply text.

Is there a way to print a figure in which there's some space reserved for such text data? (see fig. for example)

[image: Pictorial representation of the question]

Answer (score 2):

You can add some space at the bottom of the figure using [`subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust) (or whatever value of `bottom` works for you).

Then add text in the space below with `fig.text`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)

ax.plot(range(10))

fig.text(0.1,0.20,'Temp: 77K')
fig.text(0.1,0.15,'V_1: 22.4V')
fig.text(0.1,0.10,'V_1: 22.4V')
fig.text(0.1,0.05,'pump: 1064nm')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is already a good solution, but is there any way to automatically determine the amount of space required, instead of trying various values of `bottom`?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to do it is to create your figure and axes, hide one of the axes, but still use it's [`text`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text) method to place your metadata. This method uses plot coordinates, for example to get centered text, this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)
ax[1].axis('off')
ax[1].text(0.5, 0.5, 'Your-plot-metadata', ha='center', va='center')
```

will produce:

[image]

with the text centered on the hidden axes. If you want to change the proportion of these plots, have a look at [`gridspec`](http://matplotlib.org/api/gridspec_api.html#matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec).

I know matplotlib also supports [tables](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/table_demo.html) if that works better than `ax.text()` for you.